# How to findOne document by a non existent property with MongoRepository?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data

I have a bunch of documents in a MongoDB collection. A lot of these don`t have a timestamp property and I would like to add it one by one.

```java
 private final MongoRepository mongoRepository;
```

I already tried to use a Ouery to filter these documents but I got no positive answer.

```java
@Query("{'timestamp' : null}")
Document findOneIssueByMissingArchivedTimestamp();
```

Now I want to use the `findOne` function of the MongoRepository. I want find only documents which have no timestamp and return one of them. Does anybody have an idea how to do that?

Comment: Did you try `findOneByTimestampNull`? (If you're specifically trying to find just a single document for some reason, nondeterministically, you could try `findByTimestampNullLimit1`.)

Comment: No, should I create a function for this in the MongoRepo with this name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used the Spring Magic and added this function to the MongoRepository, which did the job. Thanks for the help :)

```java
Optional<Document> findFirstByTimestampIsNull();
```